# ArcGIS Desktop and Leaflet (exporting feature classes to GeoJSON)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, javascript, leaflet, geojson, export

I'm looking to access feature classes currently in ArcGIS Desktop from Leaflet (i.e. from a Web Browser with JavaScript).

I know it's possible with ArcGIS for Server (which has a "ArcGIS Data Interoperability for Server" module etc.) - I'd just have to move the data to Server and all would be good.

However, are there other options? e.g. perhaps there is a tool that can export data (as GeoJSON - which Leaflet likes) from ArcGIS Desktop.

I'm considering doing an ArcGIS Desktop add-in (extension) to export to GeoJSON if there's nothing out there.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Desktop already has a [Features to JSON](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/features-to-json.htm) tool which:

> Converts features to JSON format. The fields, geometry, and spatial
>   reference of features will be converted to their corresponding JSON
>   representation and written to a file with a **.json** extension.

and you can:

> Check the **Output to GeoJSON** parameter (**`geoJSON='GEOJSON'`** in Python) to
>   create JSON output that conforms to the GeoJSON specification. Esri
>   JSON output is the default.

This functionality appears to be new at 10.5 or 10.5.1 because it is not mentioned in the [same help page for 10.4](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/conversion-toolbox/features-to-json.htm).

Comment: Thanks - looks like you need 10.5.1 to get this option (and that the same applies to server i.e. only later versions support the format GeoJSON)..